# only one word of a sentence prints using replace method

Tags: java

As my class project I have written some codes that receives a sentence and if it has a special character by checking it's ASCII code it replaces it with another one. But unfortunately every time it replaces and shows only first word and deletes rest of the sentence. Please help me and if there's a better way for this it's appreciated.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.next();
    if (s.contains("\u0626")) {
        String result = s.replaceAll("\u0626", "\u0628");
        System.out.println(result);
    }


}


}
```

Comment: You're calling `Scanner.next()`, which returns a single token. Did you perhaps mean `nextLine()`? Note that you'll get the same behavior if you remove the `if` statement entirely, and just print `s`.

Comment: Also, unless you're trying to use regular expressions, you should use `replace`, not `replaceAll`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. As u said I changed it to nextLine() and it works like a charm. I added if cause I wanna add more characters to check.

Comment: what if I wanna check more items is it better to have more if else or use || for contains? @JonSkeet

Comment: what if I wanna check more items is it better to have more if else or use || for contains? @khelwood

Comment: Neither. Remove the `if` entirely and just put a series of `replace` calls.

Comment: Please do not try to ask lots of questions in a single post/comments. Fix the immediate problem, try everything for the next problem, ask a new question if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sure sir. Tnx for ur noticing.